# htacces rule with url variable to external url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^whatsapp$ https://web.whatsapp.com [L,NC]
```

Result:

```
If I call www.mydomain.de/whatsapp -> I will redirect to https://web.whatsapp.com
```

Now I would like realize this situation:

```
I call www.mydomain.de/whatsapp=1234567 -> I will redirect to https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=1234567
```

Can anybody helps me?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use 2 different rules:

```
RewriteRule ^whatsapp/?$ https://web.whatsapp.com [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^whatsapp=([\w-]+)/?$ https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$1 [L,NC,R=302,QSA]
```